# How to save Image Control to local file in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml

I'm writing Client-Server application, in which I get item with Image Url. This Url is binded with Image control:

```
<Image Source{Binding ImageUrl} x:Name="img_avatar" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="48" Height="48"/>
```

I want to save the image from Image.Source to the local folder without any methods which are using download operations.

Please help m someone !!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do what you ask about. When you set an Image control's source to a Uri - it gets converted to a BitmapImage which doesn't expose any API that would let you save the file or even extract a bitmap. If you want to avoid multiple downloads of the image you can download it as a file once and load a BitmapImage from the file instead of Uri.

Answer (score 0):

I believe with a little bit of reflection hackery, it should be doable. But a lot better solutions exist, so yeah..

Either subclass Image or write attached property to handle logic. All you have to do, is just load image yourself into MemoryStream and create BitmapImage manually(behind subclassed Image or attached proeprty).

This way you can expose new property that gives direct access to MemoryStream, and from there you can save file to HDD without wasting precious memory.

Bonus points if you can also keep the Source="{Binding}" syntax while providing this functionality.